# Biological analogy for boosting and inhibition idea in Hierarchical Temporal Memory (HTM)

Tags: terminology, htm

I've just watched the [9th episode of HTM school](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MSwoNAODrgk) about the "boosting" and "inhibition" ideas. However, I couldn't find the neuroscience counterpart of these terms and concepts. Since [HTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_temporal_memory) is a biologically-constrained theory, the "boosting" and "inhibition" concepts must have a neuroscience counterpart. What are they?

The video also discusses [homeostasis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeostasis) and [homeostatic regulation of neuronal excitability](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Homeostatic_Regulation_of_Neuronal_Excitability). Do these concepts have something to do with "boosting" and "inhibition"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some research, I found that "boosting" and "inhibition", in the context of HTM, are Numenta's implementation of [homeostasis](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Homeostatic_Regulation_of_Neuronal_Excitability).